# Придаточные предложения следствия

Tags: синтаксис, тип-придаточных

Снег становился всё белее и ярче, так что ломило глаза. 
"Так что ломило глаза" - это придаточные следствия?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Да, это придаточное следствия:

> 1. Вопросы: придаточные следствия отвечают на вопрос *что из этого следует*?
> 2. Средства связи: придаточные следствия прикрепляются к главному предложению при помощи союза *так что*.
> 3. Место в предложении: придаточные следствия стоят после главного предложения.
>      Пример:
>      **Снег становился всё белее и ярче, *так что* ломило глаза**, глядя на него (Л. Толстой).
>      [   ], (так что – союз).

http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/750-238_pridatochnye_sledstviya_plan_razbora_slozhnopodchinennogo_predlozheniya.html

Comment: А я уже думаю, что это причастие образа действия. Потому что можно задать вопрос насколько? Хотя, это придаточное может быть и следствия, и образа действия.